# Is it possible to load a nib file from a swift package?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, package-managers, ios14, swift-package-manager

I have created an UICollectionView Xib file and class file as a swift package. The methods in class file are accessible but I'm getting an error while loading the nib file in my project.

Link to the package: https://github.com/PranayChander/package1

Link to project: https://github.com/PranayChander/packman

import UIKit
import package1

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "PackageCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! PackageCollectionViewCell
        cell.configureCell(title: "Pram", subtitle: "dasd")
        return cell
    }
}


import UIKit

open class PackageCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet open weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet open weak var subtitleLabel: UILabel!
    
    open override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
    open func configureCell(title: String, subtitle: String) {
        self.titleLabel.text = title
        self.subtitleLabel.text = subtitle
    }
}
```

Stach Trace:
2020-12-21 14:20:37.806065+0530 packman[4341:195092] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/pranaychander/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B98131CA-B121-42B2-A0F5-FC48066C3179/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/95A42061-D137-4F35-94CE-58B8915189C6/packman.app> (loaded)' with name 'PackageCollectionViewCell''
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20420af6 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177e78 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff204209d4 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
3   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24290813 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 495
4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23d864db -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:] + 907
5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23d86bdb -[UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 88
6   packman                             0x000000010e766d19 $s7packman14ViewControllerC010collectionB0_13cellForItemAtSo012UICollectionB4CellCSo0iB0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtF + 313
7   packman                             0x000000010e766ef5 $s7packman14ViewControllerC010collectionB0_13cellForItemAtSo012UICollectionB4CellCSo0iB0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtFTo + 165
8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23d71546 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:] + 410
9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23d713a6 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 31
10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23d769cc -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 6148
11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff23d7bc48 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 351
12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24bf25b8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2924
13  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff27aa2c33 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 258
14  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff27aa91a5 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 575
15  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff27ab4f47 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 65
16  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff279f4408 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEdPd + 496
17  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff27a2b1ef _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 783
18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246ae47e __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 81
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038f120 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 12
20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038e534 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 434
21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20388f44 __CFRunLoopRun + 899
22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203886d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
23  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff2bededb3 GSEventRunModal + 139
24  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24690e0b -[UIApplication _run] + 912
25  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24695cbc UIApplicationMain + 101
26  libswiftUIKit.dylib                 0x00007fff54d1e5f2 $s5UIKit17UIApplicationMainys5Int32VAD_SpySpys4Int8VGGSgSSSgAJtF + 98
27  packman                             0x000000010e7677da $sSo21UIApplicationDelegateP5UIKitE4mainyyFZ + 122
28  packman                             0x000000010e76774e $s7packman11AppDelegateC5$mainyyFZ + 46
29  packman                             0x000000010e767829 main + 41
30  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff202593e9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/pranaychander/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B98131CA-B121-42B2-A0F5-FC48066C3179/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/95A42061-D137-4F35-94CE-58B8915189C6/packman.app> (loaded)' with name 'PackageCollectionViewCell''
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPhone 11 Pro (B98131CA-B121-42B2-A0F5-FC48066C3179) - Runtime: iOS 14.3 (18C61) - DeviceType: iPhone 11 Pro

[image]

Comment: Why did you used `nil` in the bundle param: `UINib(nibName: "PackageCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)`? What does it mean to you? I'll start with that (if your nib is correctly added to your SPM)

Comment: Please post relevant code.

Comment: @shallowThought I have attached the links to my code. Let me know in particular if there is any mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Post code, not links, please.

Comment: @Larme Have added nil as there is no other file name with "PackageCollectionViewCell". Soo that Xcode traverses through entire project to get this file.

Comment: No. You don't understand that part. If you put nil for the `bundle` param, then it's like setting `Bundle.main`, and that's your issue (see the doc: `bundleOrNil
The bundle in which to search for the nib file. If you specify nil, this method looks for the nib file in the main bundle.`). Look how to load ressources from frameworks, third party, etc. That's not by calling `Bundle.main`.

Comment: @Larme Thanks for the info. I tried accessing the third party bundle. Which is a swift package here using the following
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "PackageCollectionViewCell", bundle: Bundle(for: PackageCollectionViewCell.self)), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

Comment: So it didn't work? I'm wondering if your Package isn't faulty there. I didn't get the change to use that new SPM feature (ressources embed), but it might need some info to load them. https://medium.com/dev-genius/resources-are-coming-to-swift-packages-52e5f08ec7ad etc. You might need to modify the `Package.swift`.

Comment: No. There is almost no resources from loading xibs. Had go through the WWDC video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10169/. xibs don't need any additional configs to get them running.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: @BhumitMehta No. Haven't tried since.

Answer (score 7):

Apple says in the article [Bundling Resources with a Swift Package](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/bundling_resources_with_a_swift_package)

> Always use **`Bundle.module`** when you access resources. A package shouldn’t make assumptions about the exact location of a resource.

So you should use this static variable as bundle parameter.

Comment: This isn't available within the context of the package itself - so if you've bundled a resource and are trying to use it from within the same package, it won't work

Comment: It is. Worked for me just fine. The other way doesn't automatically work: Accessing the package's bundle files from the app that uses the package. Or did I misunderstand you? @strangetimes

Comment: That’s the only way it worked for me, accessing the names bundle of the app using the module. Bundle.module is not available when I try this within the module publishing the images. Weird.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, Bundle.module is synthesized for a Swift Package, if that package has at least one resource. You'll need to list at least one resource in target settings of the package.

Answer (score 7):

1. As others already mentioned, the bundle needs to be specified as `.module`. If you are accessing this from outside of the spm library a little extension on Bundle might be helpful.

```swift
extension Bundle {
    public static let blah = Bundle.module
}
```

2. The nib needs to be updated to deselect `Inherits Module From Target` and manually select the module where the view is located.

[image]

Comment: You, sir, have saved me **so much time** today with the "inherit module from target" checkbox suggestion! Thank you!

Comment: Step 2 saved my life

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks in the apps bundle for the NIB and can not find it (as it is in the frameworks bundle):

> Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/pranaychander/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B98131CA-B121-42B2-A0F5-FC48066C3179/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/95A42061-D137-4F35-94CE-58B8915189C6/packman.app>

Either use the identifier of the framework to get the correct bundle :

```
let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.bundleID.of.the.framework")
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "PackageCollectionViewCell", bundle: bundle)....
```

Or provide a factory function in the frameworks API to get the ready made view.

Comment: How to find the bundle identifier for a swift package? I have attached the project folder screenshot for reference.

Comment: I am not sure but think SPM uses the .library.name property as the Bundle I'd.

Answer (score 1):

If you are strictly releasing your framework for SPM then you can use the `Bundle.module` listed above as recommended. But, if you are like me and others and still need to support Pods, etc. I pulled in the `Bundle.module` to my framework and used `MyFramework.module` as my Bundle.

```
public class MyFramework: NSObject {
    static let bundleName = "MyFramework"

    public static let bundle = Bundle(for: Self.self)!

    /// Returns the resource bundle associated with the current Swift module. This is required for SPM use
    public static var module: Bundle = {
        let bundleName = "MyFramework" // May be "MyFramework_MyFramework" for you

        let candidates = [
            // Bundle should be present here when the package is linked into an App.
            Bundle.main.resourceURL,

            // Bundle should be present here when the package is linked into a framework.
            Bundle(for: MyFramework.self).resourceURL,

            // For command-line tools.
            Bundle.main.bundleURL
        ]

        for candidate in candidates {
            let bundlePath = candidate?.appendingPathComponent(bundleName + ".bundle")
            if let bundle = bundlePath.flatMap(Bundle.init(url:)) {
                return bundle
            }
        }
        return MyFramework.bundle
    }()
}
```

Once you have that you can just use `MyFramework.module`